# How are the open sets of $[0,1]^\omega$ endowed with the uniform topology?

Tags: general-topology

My atempt: Obviously, the basic sets are open balls $B(x,\epsilon)$. It is easy to see that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset \Pi_{\alpha \in \omega} B(x_{\alpha}, \epsilon)$, but the 'reverse inclusion' is not necessarely true. For instance, consider $ \phantom {.}x=(\frac{1}{2})$, $ \phantom{.}\epsilon = \frac{1}{4}$ and $ y=(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{n+3})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. $\phantom{.} \bar{\rho} (x,y) = 1/4$, which implies that $y \notin B(x,\epsilon)$.

Comment: Maybe you mean $y=(\frac14 - \frac{1}{n+3})_{n \in \Bbb N}$ instead? Its *reverse* inclusion, not converse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way to describe the open balls:

$$B(x,r)=\bigcup\left\{\prod_{n\in\omega}B(x_n,s):0<s<r\right\}\,;$$

I’ll leave it to you to prove that it’s correct.

Comment: @JohnMars Note that this shows that $B(x,r)$ is box-open and so the uniform-metric topology is a subset of the box topology on $[0,1]^\omega$.